# Questions about object has no attribute(Python)

Tags: python

When I try to change my teacher's code to create a new dialog, the shell always shows that `NameDialog object has no attribute _column_enter`.

However, my teacher's code can work so I am wondering, what's the difference to make my code can not work:

```
import tkinter

Font=('Helvetica', 14)


class User_design:
    def __init__(self):
        self._root_window=tkinter.Tk()
        start_button=tkinter.Button(
            master=self._root_window, text='click there to start.',
            font=Font, command=self._get_start)
        start_button.grid(
            row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10,
            sticky = tkinter.S)



        self._greeting_text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self._greeting_text.set('Not begin')

        greeting_label = tkinter.Label(
            master = self._root_window, textvariable = self._greeting_text,
            font =  Font)

        greeting_label.grid(
            row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10,
            sticky = tkinter.N)

        self._root_window.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self._root_window.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self._root_window.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)





    def start(self) -> None:
        self._root_window.mainloop()

    def _get_start(self):
        dialog = NameDialog()
        dialog.show()

        if dialog.was_ok_clicked():
            column=dialog.get_column()
            row=dialog.get_row()
            turn=dialog.get_turn()
            top_left=dialog.get_top_left()
            win_method=dialog.get_win_method()


class NameDialog:
    def __init__(self):
        self._dialog_window = tkinter.Toplevel()

        #column_label
        column_label=tkinter.Label(
            master=self._dialog_window, text='How many columns?',
            font=Font)
        column_label.grid(
            row=0, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)
        self._column_entry = tkinter.Entry(
            master = self._dialog_window, width = 20, font = Font)
        self._column_enter.grid(
            row=0, column=1, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)



        #row_input
        row_input=tkinter.Label(
            master=self._dialog_window, text='How many rows?',
            font=Font)
        row_input.grid(
            row=1, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)
        self._row_entry = tkinter.Entry(
            master = self._dialog_window, width = 20, font = Font)
        self._row_enter.grid(
            row=1, column=1, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)

        #turn_input
        turn_input=tkinter.Label(
            master=self._dialog_window, text='Which color move first?',
            font=Font)
        turn_input.grid(
            row=2, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)
        self._turn_entry = tkinter.Entry(
            master = self._dialog_window, width = 20, font = Font)
        self._turn_enter.grid(
            row=2, column=1, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)

        #top_left_input
        top_left_input=tkinter.Label(
            master=self._dialog_window, text='Which color on top left?',
            font=Font)
        top_left_input.grid(
            row=3, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)
        self._top_left_entry = tkinter.Entry(
            master = self._dialog_window, width = 20, font = Font)
        self._top_left_enter.grid(
            row=3, column=1, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)

        #win_menthod_input
        win_method_input=tkinter.Label(
            master=self._dialog_window, text='win method?',
            font=Font)
        win_method_input.grid(
            row=4, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)
        self._win_method_entry = tkinter.Entry(
            master = self._dialog_window, width = 20, font = Font)
        self._win_method_enter.grid(
            row=4, column=1, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)



        button_frame = tkinter.Frame(master = self._dialog_window)
        button_frame.grid(
            row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10,
            sticky = tkinter.E + tkinter.S)
        ok_button = tkinter.Button(
            master = button_frame, text = 'OK', font = Font,
            command = self._on_ok_button)
        ok_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        cancel_button = tkinter.Button(
            master = button_frame, text = 'Cancel', font = Font,
            command = self._on_cancel_button)
        cancel_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)


        self._dialog_window.rowconfigure(5, weight = 1)
        self._dialog_window.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)


        self._ok_clicked = False
        self._column = ''
        self._row = ''
        self._turn=''
        self._top_left=''
        self._win_method=''


    def show(self):
        self._dialog_window.grab_set()
        self._dialog_window.wait_window()

    def was_ok_clicked(self) -> bool:
        return self._ok_clicked


    def get_column(self) -> str:
        return self._column


    def get_row(self) -> str:
        return self._row

    def get_turn(self)->str:
        return self._turn

    def get_top_left(self)->str:
        return self._top_left

    def get_win_method(self)->str:
        return self._win_method

    def _on_ok_button(self) -> None:
        self._ok_clicked = True
        self._column = self._column_entry.get()
        self._row = self._row_entry.get()
        self._turn = self._turn_entry.get()
        self._top_left = self._top_left_entry.get()
        self._win_menthod = self._win_method_entry.get()

        self._dialog_window.destroy()


    def _on_cancel_button(self) -> None:
        self._dialog_window.destroy()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    User_design().start()
```

Comment: Ctrl-f-ing for "_column_enter" gives only one hit in your code. Check for typos.

Answer (score 0):

```
self._column_entry = tkinter.Entry(
            master = self._dialog_window, width = 20, font = Font)
self._column_enter.grid(
            row=0, column=1, padx=10,pady=10, sticky=tkinter.W)
```

because your spell wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are around 5 sections of your code where you refer to `enter` instead of `entry`, so the variable you are trying to set does not exist.

Search and replace `enter` with `entry` and you should be good to go.